# Building ns-2 on Cygwin

Tags: gcc, cygwin, ns2

I'm installing NS2 on Cygwin. I've installed gcc. It seems there is no link between Cygwin and required packages. gcc version is 5.4.0 . 
There is "Package ... is not present on your system." for each package.

```
Checking Cygwin version is >= 1.3.12... 2.5.2 (should be ok)
Checking filesystems are mounted as UNIX filetype... yes
Checking default mode is binmode... yes
Checking legitimate login name... ok
Checking legitimate path name... ok
Checking for gcc... NO!

Package gcc is not present on your system.

Please install it using Cygwin's setup.exe
before trying to install the ns-2 distribution.

The above test indicates that your installation of Cygwin
is probably NOT SUITABLE for installing ns-2 allinone.
(More details can be found in the specific error message above.)

Do you wish to proceed regardless? [y/N] y

*** OK, but you're on your own... ***

Checking for gcc-g++... ok
Checking for gawk... ok
Checking for tar... ok
Checking for gzip... ok
Checking for make... ok
Checking for patch... NO!

Package patch is not present on your system.

Please install it using Cygwin's setup.exe
before trying to install the ns-2 distribution.

The above test indicates that your installation of Cygwin
is probably NOT SUITABLE for installing ns-2 allinone.
(More details can be found in the specific error message above.)

Do you wish to proceed regardless? [y/N] y

*** OK, but you're on your own... ***

Checking for perl... NO!

Package perl is not present on your system.
```

When I try to install Cygwin packages and checked every package to be install, there is "Nothing needed to be installed" message.

Comment: There is a config.log (or similar) to look for the gcc and perl failed tests ?

Comment: A hint : Please use the updated ns-allinone-2.35_gcc482.tar.gz for gcc/g++ versions 4.6 ... 5.2 (Probably OK with v5.4) 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSGJCZ2YzUGJDVk0/view?usp=sharing .... Hint 2 : Why not use a genuine 'Linux OS' instead of the "look alike Cygwin" ? ... Easy to install : Install 'VirtualBox', and install one or more Linux OS into VirtualBox.

Comment: Looked on the ns-2.35 source code. The configure is a disaster and very obsolete. I expect that also on a Linux system a manual tweak of the configure will be needed. It will be easier than cygwin but not clean.

Comment: @KnudLarsen I started using Ubuntu but I had faced so much errors there...

Comment: » I started using Ubuntu but I had faced so much errors there « : Ubuntu is probably not the best choice for ns2. Some additions can use Ubuntu, some not. About Ubuntu 16.04 : The system g++-5.3.1 cannot be used for the most ns2. Etc. etc. ... The safe choice is often the two CentOS 6.8, either i386 or/and x86_64. ... All depending on the protocols you want to use. http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.8/isos/ → CentOS-6.8-[arch]-LiveCD.iso .... About ./configure in ns-2.35/ : Don't do that. The safe command is ./install, in ns-allinone-2.35/ .

Comment: @matzeri I have 24 config.log files.

Comment: look on the one as the `Checking for gcc... NO!`

Answer (score 0):

My 2c$. Don't waste time with ns-2 except if you want to dig in old style build system and obsolete assumption and spend a lot of time in complicated header quests.
If no one updated the source file for 5 years, may be there are better software.

ns-2 requires octl a specific object orienteted TCL used only by ns-2 plus another similar packages. The octl configure rejects CPPFLAGS declaration. To properly catch all the tcl headers and lib on cygwin you need:

remove "tcl-generic/" by the directories include list.

replace "dylib" with "dll.a" to cath the shared lib

In the resulting configure add manually "-I/usr/include/tcl8.5/unix" as there seems no other way to force it.

After that will start the quest of header mismatch; I stopped at the first one as it looked a long activity.

I suspect it will be not worth the effort also on a a Linux system.